# Recursive function not returning a value

Tags: vb.net, user-interface

I have a gui program that contains a lot of controls which have tags that act as pointers to a partner machine's memory location. On pressing a button, I need to find the values of the controls which correspond to a list of tags and send these values to the relevant memory location on the partner machine. I have most of this set up fine, but I am having issues with the part of the code that finds the control with the matching tag and returning the value from that control.

```
   Private Function tag_to_value(tabpage As Object, tagvalue As String) As Double

        For Each tempitem In tabpage.Controls
            If tag_to_value <> Nothing Then Return tag_to_value
            If TypeOf tempitem Is TabControl Then
                Dim tabpagecollection As TabControl
                tabpagecollection = DirectCast(tempitem, TabControl)
                Dim tmppage As TabPage
                For Each tmppage In tabpagecollection.TabPages
                    tag_to_value = tag_to_value(tmppage, tagvalue)
                Next
            ElseIf TypeOf tempitem Is Panel Then
                Dim panelcollection As Panel
                panelcollection = DirectCast(tempitem, Panel)
                tag_to_value = tag_to_value(panelcollection, tagvalue)
            ElseIf tempitem.Tag <> Nothing Then
                '    If IsNumeric(tempitem.Tag) Then
                If tempitem.Tag = tagvalue Then
                    If TypeOf tempitem Is CheckBox Then
                        'tempitem.Checked = tagvalue
                        'tag_to_value = tempitem.checked
                        Return CDbl(tempitem.checked)
                    ElseIf TypeOf tempitem Is TextBox Then
                        'tag_to_value = CDbl(tempitem.text)
                        Return CDbl(tempitem.text)
                    ElseIf TypeOf tempitem Is TrackBar Then
                        'tag_to_value = tempitem.value
                        Return CDbl(tempitem.value)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next

    End Function
```

In the above, I can use breakpoints and see that at the return cdbl(tempitem.value) line, the tempitem.value is correct to the control, but in the sub that calls it, tag_to_value returns as 0 always.

Comment: Your mixing and matching of `Return` statements and using the implicit local variable named after the method is a recipe for confusion. Choose one or the other and use only it. Choose `Return` statements. We're not in VB6 any more , Toto. Once you've done that, you need to debug your code properly if there's still an issue.

Comment: You really should set [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project (and set it as the default for new projects). It will point out where variable types do not match and give some helpful suggestions as to how to fix various parts of that code.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that helped a lot to clean up everything. This is my first project that's not VBA based so this should give some idea of how experienced I am! It didn't help solve the issue I was having, but I figured out that my issue was due to not exiting the for each tmppage loop upon finding a non zero value